# Why does JavaScript display 01002004 as 6295553?

Tags: javascript, alert

I have the codes below:

```
<script type="javascript">
   var item = 001002004;
   alert(item);
</script>
```

Whenever I see this page in **view source** in my web browser, I see these lines of code exactly as same as here. But when `alert()` function runs, I see an unknown message. It alrest '6295553'. I don't know where is this unknown value from. I'm sure anything don't happen to `item` and it did not change before of `alert`.

What do you think ? What's the problem ?

Comment: Are you saying that is the _only_ code on your page? The value is set immediately before the alert?

Comment: Working fine at my end... Which browser you are using? Try hitting refreshing the cache first and than try.. Hit ctrl + f5 before the page loads and than try.

Comment: I have lots of codes, but care about this point that I can see the right value in view-source, but I get another value in alert().

Comment: I dont think this makes any sense. I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: value may be automatically generated. Are you using any java/.net platform ? Keep the brekpoint on var item and check the actual value returned at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Any number prefixed with 0 will be considered as octal. and 0x for hexa decimal**

I am guessing that you are having it as an numeric value like below or using parseInt function to parse the string and when you alert it you see a different value..

```
var item = 001002004;
alert(item);
```

Or probably you are doing something like below

```
var item = '001002004';
alert(parseInt(item));
```

See more details on [**parseInt**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) @MDN

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/nTT2V/)**

Comment: See now, forgot to add the link ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the script type to "text/javascript" `<script type="text/javascript">`, or don't use the `type` attribute at all. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8f9eN/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3jK2v/

Please have a look at above fiddle. It does not alert anything anomalous for me.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are not changing the variable -- maybe with a cap.  eg

```
   var item = 'some value';
   alert(Item);
```